# Android: Passing float values from Java to JNI is always NaN

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, nan

Short version: I can pass double values from Java to C++ using a JNI jdouble.  However, when I use floats, the C++ jfloat parameter is always NaN.

Longer version:
I'm modifying the hello-gl2 Android sample for VS 2015 which draws a triangle (https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/hello-gl2-android-3b61896c), adding a simple function to rotate the triangle.

In gl_code.cpp:

```
extern "C" {
    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_android_gl2jni_GL2JNILib_updateAngle(JNIEnv * env, jfloat dAngle);
};
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_android_gl2jni_GL2JNILib_updateAngle(JNIEnv * env, jfloat dAngle)
{
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "DEBUG", "updateAngle: %f", dAngle);
    rotationAngle += dAngle;
}
```

And in GL2JNILib.java:

```
public class GL2JNILib {
    public static native void updateAngle(float dAngle);
}
```

And this is all called from the GL2JNIView.java:

```
GL2JNILib.updateAngle(0.5f);
```

The VS debugger shows the value of jfloat dAngle to be nan(3b52bc) no matter what value I pass from Java, logcat shows "nan" and OpenGL confirms this by drawing nothing.

I'm running on a Nexus 9 hardware device.  When using the Nexus_5_API_22_x86 emulator, I seem to get many different values, sometimes NaN, even though I'm always passing in 0.5f.  If I replace "jfloat" with "jdouble" and "float" with "double" in all the code above, everything works fine on the device and emulator.

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the 2nd parameter in the native method: `jclass`.  Your method signature in C should be:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
    Java_com_android_gl2jni_GL2JNILib_updateAngle(JNIEnv *env,
                                                  jclass classz,
                                                  jfloat dAngle);
```

The 2nd parameter is a `jclass` because your method is `static`.  If it were an instance method for the class then the 2nd parameter would be a `jobject` (the `this` for the object.)  You might consider using the "javah" tool to help you generate method signatures.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I have no idea why it worked for doubles, but I was indeed missing the 2nd parameter and now all is well.

Comment: It worked for doubles because 64-bit arguments must be 64-bit aligned on the stack. The `classz` argument got the 32-bit padding.